# Print a color document on a B&W printer, with good color separation

Tags: microsoft-word, printing, colors, adobe-acrobat

I want to print a PDF document converted from Word by Adobe Acrobat Pro. It has some figures containing colors that when I convert to black & white are distinguishable but after printing by a black & white printer (High Quality printer that is not my own) all appear the same gray.

How can I change Adobe Acrobat Pro or Word 2010 settings for best printing results?

Answer (score 1):

Is your B&W printer actually a grayscale laser printer?  If so, do not convert the document to black and white.  Just print it normally and the printer driver should convert the image to grayscale automatically.

Comment: Thanks, but as I mentioned, some colors with similar intensity are printed alike, but the colors are important for me. my only solution now is to change one color by Photoshop but it dose not give the best possible output.

Comment: When you click print, click the properties or preferences button on the print dialog box.  Usually, the print driver has options for converting color images to black & white.

Answer (score 0):

I would fiddle with the advanced printing settings in Adobe Acrobat Pro.

1. Choose **File** and then **Print**.
2. Click the **Advanced** button at the bottom of the **Print** dialog
   box.
3. Under **Color Management** try ticking or unticking some options, I would especially try disabling "Treat greys as k-only greys" if it isn't already.